# Chern classes and Hilber polynomial.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about Chern classes. The first one is general. If $X$ is a projective scheme and $F$ a coherent sheaf over $X$. We define the Hilbert polynomial $P_F(n):= \chi(X,F(m))$, where $F(m)$ is the twisted sheaf. If I denote with $ch(F(m))$ the Chen character and with $td(X)$ the Todd class, we have the equality
$$ \chi(X,F(m))= \int_X ch(F(m)) \, \dot \, td(X) \,\,\,\, ?$$

Answer (score 4):

This is the statement of the [Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem) applied to the structure morphism $f:X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$. This is a generalization of the [Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem) which gives the same statement but for holomorphic vector bundles on a compact complex manifold.